# getElementsBy returning blank values with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

First time posting to Stack Overflow and novice VBA coder.

I wrote a code in VBA to scrape data from a website. I am able to get all the info I need except for one element, which for some reason keeps returning a blank value when I use Debug.Print

The HTML code and Url that I am unable to extract is the following:
Url:  linkedin.com/school/mcgill-university/people/?keywords=zkzk

```html
<div class="container p0">
    <div class="display-flex full-width justify-space-between align-items-center pt5 ph5">
      <span class="t-20 t-black">
          0 alumni
      </span>
```

I would like to printout "0 alumni" so I wrote the following VBA code:

```
Dim aEle As Object
Dim Number As String
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

Number = aEle.objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("display-flex full-width justify-space-between 
         align-items-center pt5 ph5").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
         Debug.Print Number
```

But all I get is an empty value (i.e., nothing shows in the immediate window and when I hover over (Number) it shows the value as " ")

The part of the HTML code that works is this:

```html
<div id="ember1418" class="org-people-profile-card ember-view">
<section id="ember1419" class="artdeco-card artdeco-card--with-hover ember-view"><!---->
  <div class="org-people-profile-card__profile-info">
<div id="ember1425" class="artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view">
<a data-control-name="people_profile_card_name_link" href="/in/x-060210b2/" id="ember1426" class="link-without-visited-state ember-view">
<div id="ember1427" 
class="org-people-profile-card__profile-title t-black lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--single-line ember-view">  jane doe

<!----></div>
</a>
```

And the VBA code I wrote to printout "jane doe" is this:

```
For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("org-people-profile-card ember-view")

            Name = aEle.getElementsByClassName("artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view")(0).innerText
                Debug.Print Name 
Next
```

Jane doe prints out as expected.

I am confused by the discrepancy; even though they are both class elements containing inner text and I am using the same "getElementsbyClassName" VBA command, one works but not the other? Is there something different about the first section of HTML code? Do I need to modify the VBA code to be able to print out "0 alumni"?

P.S. I shortened the original VBA code and only included the parts relevant to the question.

Comment: Your first attempt which started with `Number =` should throw an error as you defined `.getElementsByTagName()` on an array of element. Rectified approach will be `aEle.objIE.document.getElementsByClassName()(0).getElementsByTagName()(0).innerText`. However, can you share the site url to get a specific answer?

Comment: The URL for the first HTML code is https://www.linkedin.com/school/mcgill-university/people/?keywords=zkzk

I'm not sure I understand the rectified approach. Are you saying that I should write the same command but without specificying the class and tag names and just leave the () empty?

Btw, I am not getting any errors. The code runs through but I just don't get the expected output (in this case I'm getting no value when I should get "0 alumni")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line

```
Number = Split(aEle.objIE.document.querySelector(".container div span").innerText, " ")(0)
```

This line worked fine for me

```
Debug.Print .document.querySelector(".container div span").innerText
```

Comment: Sadly still doesn't return a value

Comment: Can you share the URL ..?

Comment: The URL for the first HTML code is linkedin.com/school/mcgill-university/people/?keywords=zkzk

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you still have a problem, share the whole code so as to be able to help you ..

Comment: it worked! I had to add objIE as I was getting an error, but I was finally able to get the print out I was looking for. Thanks!